# Solidity interface error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am trying to connect two different Smart Contracts using interfaces. Here is my contract `CRUD.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract CRUD {

struct Data {
    uint id;
    bytes32 contentHash;
    string description;
}

// Variables de estado 
Data[] data;

uint nextId;

// Operaciones CRUD: CREATE, READ, UPDATE y DELETE:

// Operación CREATE
function createData(string memory _description) public{
    bytes32 contentHash = createHash(_description);
    data.push(Data(nextId, contentHash, _description));
    nextId++;
}



// Operación READ por búsqueda del id
function readData(uint _id) public view returns (uint, bytes32,string memory) {
    uint index = findIndex(_id);
    return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
}

// Operación READ por búsqueda del hash de la entrada de datos
function readDataByHash(bytes32 _hash) public view returns (uint, bytes32,string memory) {
    uint index = findByHash(_hash);
    return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
}

//Operacion READ todos las entradas de datos
function readAllData() external view returns (Data[] memory){
    return data;
}

function count() external view returns (uint){
    return data.length;
}

// Operación UPDATE
function updateData(uint _id, string memory _description) public returns (uint, bytes32, string memory){
    uint index =  findIndex(_id);
    bytes32 contentHash = createHash(_description);
    data[index].contentHash= contentHash;
    data[index].description = _description;
    return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
}

// Operación DELETE
function deleteData(uint _id) public{
    uint index = findIndex(_id);
    delete data[index];
}

// Creación del hash
function createHash(string memory _description) internal pure returns (bytes32){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_description));
}

// Búsqueda del id
function findIndex(uint _id) internal view returns (uint) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id == _id) {                
            return i;
        }
    }
    revert("Data not found");
}

// Busqueda por el hash de la entrada de datos
function findByHash(bytes32 _contentHash) internal view returns (uint) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].contentHash == _contentHash) {                
            return i;
        }
    }
    revert("Data not found");
}
}
```

Here is the other contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface ICRUD{ function readAllData() external view returns (Data[] memory); }

contract verifyData{

function read() external view returns (Data[] memory){
     Data[] data = ICRUD(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).readAllData();
     return data;
}
}
```

My purpose is to call readAllData function from verifyData contract but Remix just keeps returning the following error:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
--> verifyData.sol:5:51:
|
5 | function readAllData() external view returns (Data[] memory);
| ^^^^
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue refers that in your interface doesn't exist the implementation about `Data` struct. To solve it, you should move the declaration of this struct inside interface and modify your smart contracts similar to this way:

CRUD.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// NOTE: I imported the smart contract where interface has declared
import "verifyData.sol";

contract CRUD is ICRUD {
    // Variables de estado 
    Data[] data;

    uint nextId;

    // Operaciones CRUD: CREATE, READ, UPDATE y DELETE:

    // Operación CREATE
    function createData(string memory _description) public{
        bytes32 contentHash = createHash(_description);
        data.push(Data(nextId, contentHash, _description));
        nextId++;
    }

    // Operación READ por búsqueda del id
    function readData(uint _id) public view returns (uint, bytes32,string memory) {
        uint index = findIndex(_id);
        return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
    }

    // Operación READ por búsqueda del hash de la entrada de datos
    function readDataByHash(bytes32 _hash) public view returns (uint, bytes32,string memory) {
        uint index = findByHash(_hash);
        return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
    }

    // NOTE: I override this function because I made that this smart contract implements with
    //       ICRUD interface.
    function readAllData() override external view returns (Data[] memory){
        return data;
    }

    function count() external view returns (uint){
        return data.length;
    }

    // Operación UPDATE
    function updateData(uint _id, string memory _description) public returns (uint, bytes32, string memory){
        uint index =  findIndex(_id);
        bytes32 contentHash = createHash(_description);
        data[index].contentHash= contentHash;
        data[index].description = _description;
        return (data[index].id, data[index].contentHash, data[index].description);
    }

    // Operación DELETE
    function deleteData(uint _id) public{
        uint index = findIndex(_id);
        delete data[index];
    }

    // Creación del hash
    function createHash(string memory _description) internal pure returns (bytes32){
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_description));
    }

    // Búsqueda del id
    function findIndex(uint _id) internal view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].id == _id) {                
                return i;
            }
        }
        revert("Data not found");
    }

    // Busqueda por el hash de la entrada de datos
    function findByHash(bytes32 _contentHash) internal view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].contentHash == _contentHash) {                
                return i;
            }
        }
        revert("Data not found");
    }
}
```

verifyData.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface ICRUD {
    // NOTE: Declare inside interface the Data struct implementation
    struct Data {
        uint id;
        bytes32 contentHash;
        string description;
    }

    function readAllData() external view returns (Data[] memory); 
}

contract verifyData is ICRUD {
    ICRUD ICrud;
    
    // NOTE: When deploy verifyData, you must pass the address of CRUD smart contract
    constructor(address _interfaceAddress) {
        ICrud = ICRUD(_interfaceAddress);
    }

    function readAllData() override external view returns (Data[] memory){
        Data[] memory data = ICrud.readAllData();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Inside both smart contracts I added some notes let you know every single modifies that I made.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replay. However, i dont understand why you made that import, is it necessary? Can you import contracts deployed in geth? I dont really understand imports